# Viewer pane is printing in the wrong dimensions

Tags: r, rstudio

My plots are showing up with the titles way too zoomed it. They are printing like my available space is much smaller than it really is. It was working fine before. I've tried to reset it with `dev.off()` and `par(mfrow=c(2,2))`.

`plot(mtcars$mpg)`

Do you see how the dimensions are weird? I've also tried to clear the preivous plots.

[image]

This is the same plot printed on another computer with the viewerport set to about the same size.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `par(mfrow = c(1,1))`? 2,2 scales the viewer to show 4 plots.

Comment: Yes, I tried that.